# One second time interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

In one of the filter options on my site, the user can select a date range and a time range. I have no problem with the date. But over time there is a question.

I am using the DatePicker from react-datepicker.
To display the time, I use the format "HH:mm:ss" and added parameter timeIntervals={1}.
Accordingly, the user can select the time with a frequency of one minute.

[image]

However, not in vain are the seconds nearby.
And I would like to allow the user to select the time for each second. as below

[image]

There are no ready-made solutions in this library. And I could not find solutions on the Internet and any information in the documentation. Perhaps you can help me.

Below is  my code

```
    export default function FilterDateTime({ isExpanded, setIsExpanded }) {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date());
  
  const filterPassedTime = (time) => {
  const selectedDate = new Date(time);
  return selectedDate.getTime() > startDate.getTime();
  };


  return (
    <ArrowDropdown
        isExpanded={isExpanded}
        setIsExpanded={setIsExpanded}
        title="Date and Time range"
        onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!isExpanded)}>
                  <>
    <DatePicker

      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm:ss"
      timeIntervals={1}
      timeCaption="Time"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy         HH:mm:ss"
      calendarStartDay={1}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {e.preventDefault();}}
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
    />
    
    <DatePicker
      selected={endDate}
      onChange={(date) => setEndDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      timeFormat="HH:mm:ss"
      timeIntervals={1}
      timeCaption="time"
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy         HH:mm:ss"
      calendarStartDay={1}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {e.preventDefault();}}
      selectsEnd
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      minDate={startDate}
      filterTime={filterPassedTime}
    />
    </>

    </ArrowDropdown>
  );
}
```

P.S. Since it is possible that this feature cannot be done. I can allow the user to enter seconds on their own (at the moment I have the input completely closed). But given the factor that a second in the end date cannot be less than a second in the start date.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently not supported by react-datepicker but I can see the feature is already developed but is under PR review , might take some time to roll out.

Here is the github pr for same

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/pull/3214

Comment: This is bad news for me. Perhaps you will advise me a library in which I can set the range by date and time range, taking into account seconds

Comment: Or, leaving this library, let the user enter seconds manually, given the fact that the second of the end time cannot be less than the second of the start (the input field is currently closed for me)